# How to create a Mongo database to Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have created the backend operations using Node.js / MongoDB and created services for them, but when I run the server it indicates that I've connected successfully, but I can't see a database in Robo 3T.

Here is what I coded:

```
DBConfig.js 

var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({

name : {
type : String,
require : true
},

address : {
type : String,
require : true  
}
});

mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = mongoose;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/TestDB4', function(err){

if(err)
{
console.log(err);
process.exit(-1);
}
console.log("Connected to the db")
});
```

I can't see an error. Why isn't the DB created?

Answer (score 0):

**check your User.Controller.js as this below,**

```
var mongoose        = require('../DBSchema/SchemaMapper');
var UserSchema      = mongoose.model('User');

var UserController = function(){
    this.insert = (data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var user = new UserSchema({
                userName: data.userName,
                password: data.password
            });
            user.save().then(() => {
                resolve({status: 200, message: "Added new user"});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- "+err});
            })
        })

    }

    this.update = (id, data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.update({_id: id}, data).then(() => {
                resolve({status: 200, message: "update user"});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- " + err});
            })
        })
    }

    this.searchAll = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.find().exec().then((data) => {
                resolve({status: 200, data: data});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- " + err});
            })
        })
    }

    this.search = (id) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.find({_id:id}).exec().then(user => {
                resolve({status: 200, data: user});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message: "Error:- " + err});
            })
        })
    }

    this.delete = (id) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            UserSchema.remove({_id:id}).then(() => {
                resolve({status: 200, message: "remove user"});
            }).catch(err => {
                reject({status: 500, message:"Error:- " + err});
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = new UserController();
```

**And User.Route.js as below,**

```
var express     = require('express');
var router      = express.Router();
var Controller  = require('./User.Controller');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    Controller.insert(req.body).then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    })
});


router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Controller.update(req.params.id, req.body).then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    })
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Controller.searchAll().then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({data: data.data});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    });
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Controller.search(req.params.id).then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({data: data.data});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    });
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Controller.delete(req.params.id).then(data => {
        res.status(data.status).send({message: data.message});
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(err.status).send({message: err.message});
    })
})
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

**check your app.js as follows**

```
const Express       = require("express");
const BodyParser    = require("body-parser");
const Routes        = require("./Routes");
const Cors          = require("cors");

const app = Express();
app.use(Cors());

app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use('/', Routes);

app.listen(8083, 'localhost', (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
    console.log("Server listen port 8083");
});
```

**and Routes.js as follows,**

```
var Express         = require("express");
var Routes          = Express.Router();
var UserRoute       = require('./src/User/User.Route');
var CommentRoute    = require('./src/Comment/Comment.Route');

Routes.use('/user/', UserRoute);
Routes.use('/comment/', CommentRoute);

module.exports = Routes;
```